# Sharepoint 2013 'start a process task' options

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have the following questions about using 'start a task process' in SharePoint Designer 2013:

1. When a user either rejects or accepts a task that they have been assigned to, the outcome local variable value is either 0 or 1.    Right now I am updating a custom list with the value obtained from the local variable called 'outcome'. Is there a way to obtain the outcome value as 'rejected' or 'accepted' instead of 0 or 1? If so can you tell me how to change the outcome values?
2. For the 'start a task process', I am picking the option for allowing only the first person in the group needing to accept or request the task. This works fine. However when I look at the other people that could have accepted/rejected the request, each person has a workflow waiting for them to process. Thus since only the first person did the accepted/reject the task, how can the worflows for the other people not be in the que for to 'process' the same request?
3. Based upon the default, if a task has been accepted/rejected by a user, that is the way the task reamins.Is there a way to undo an accept or reject message? If so, how would you accomplish this task?

If you can answer any of the question(s) above, I would appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I see this is from 3 months ago, but here you go:

1. you will get 0 for the first option, 1 for the second, 2 for the third etc. You can test (If any value  any value) for the Outcome and set a workflow variable to the actual values: "accept", "reject" etc. Then you can set your list field to this variable.
2. if you only wait for the first response (for parallel assignment), after the first user completes the task, the workflow automatically cancels the other tasks and notifies the other people by e-mail.
3. This would be much more complicated to do. You would need to set the task process not to wait for it's outcome and in parallel enter a loop which waits some period over the first response / all responses and then checks the final outcome - again much more complicated.

Don't forget to mark as an answer.
Cheers,
Alex.